# Understanding JWT

Tags: javascript, jwt

I've spent a couple weeks trying to wrap my head around JWT objects. The premise makes sense but where I get confused is the security aspect. If I am a Javascript Client (e.g. Firebase) and want to send a secure request to an api using Open Auth, I would encrypt my message with a key. However, since the client source may be viewed how can I secure my Key so malicious requests don't go through. Am I missing something. Is there a way to secure the key?

Comment: Maybe this article help you to clarify some concepts: https://realpython.com/blog/python/token-based-authentication-with-flask/ This is about Python and Flask but the ideas are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encryption process is performed using the public key of the recipient.
Your client has no private key to generate and manage.

If you want to receive and decrypt such JWT, then your client has to create a key pair (private and public) for the session only and then exchange the public key with the server.

Comment: Ah, so upon validation the client receives the public key for encryption.That makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: The client receives the public keys or has to get them through a known manner (e.g. URI such as google one => https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs)

Answer (score 4):

Joel, I think you got the directions wrong ;)

One would use JWT within the OAuth protocol to achieve what some people might call "[Stateless Authentication](https://www.jbspeakr.cc/purpose-jwt-stateless-authentication/)", meaning that the auth server would issue a signed token (for e.g. a client application or a user) after successful authentication (of the client or user) without storing info about/ of it, which would be required when using opaque token.

The signed token could be used by your JS client to e.g. call a certain REST-API endpoint (on a so-called resource server) that would verify the signature of the token and authorize your request or not, based on the content (the claims) of the JWT.

Both, your client application as well as the resource server are able to introspect the token and verify its signature because they either have a shared secret with the auth server (who used the secret to sign the token in the first place) or know the public key that corresponds to the private key the auth server used to sign the token (as Florent mentioned in his comment).

JWTs can also be encrypted, which is useful if the resource server or the auth server require sensitive information but don't want to store/ access the data. You would not be able to introspect it as long as you don't have the used encryption secret.

... long story short, the OAuth protocol describes client auth against a resource or an auth server. JWT can be used to transfer auth prove (as a Bearer token within the Authorization header). However, the idea of using JWT in the OAuth flow is not to "send a secure request to an api".

Comment: thanks for clarifying that its about signing the JWT not encrypting it. Thats an important point when trying to understand JWT

Answer (score 0):

When building an api server, I prefer the client do the encryption process on their own server, and send the encrypted data after that. Everything is under https.

If the encryption somehow must be done on the web client side, I prefer the key to be very short-lived & time based, and both the api server and client have the agreed special algorithm to generate that key again. Therefore, if the key is hacked somehow, the attacker can not benefit in long term.